# Stack Exchange API - Get Watched Tags for a User

Tags: feature-request, api, api-v2.2, tags

Is there a way to get a list of tags that the user has set up as "Watched Tags"? If not, is it on the roadmap?

Answer (score 1):

No, this information is not exposed via the API (and it's not available in SEDE either). At the moment, your best bet is probably to scrape the [tag notifications page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/tag-notifications/current), though this only works for your own account.

A similar question (asking for the number of users watching a certain tag, instead of the other way around) was posted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317889/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange. User @rene found a way to scrape it from the website; see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274622/295232) for his solution. It could be that the rename / new functionality (tag favorites -> tag watching) broke it, I haven't tested it.

Comment: This answer does not relate to the question. OP is asking for "Watched Tags for a User" whereas the referenced links are for "Number of Users watching a tag"

Comment: @acron huh, I guess you're right. Not sure what I was thinking back then. I've updated the answer with an alternative.